# Excel: count how many times a value appears once across two columns based off another value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to write a sumproduct formula which calculates how many times a value appears once across two columns based off another value in another column. For example:

[image]

I am trying to evaluate how many star students Mr .G had over the course of two terms. We can see that Mr. G had 3 students at some point over the course of the two terms were a star student. However, I am having issues getting to 3 without double counting Bob twice.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps this option is suitable for you - `=SUMPRODUCT(N((TRIM(B2:B5)="Star")+(TRIM(C2:C5)="Star")>0);N((TRIM(D2:D5)="Mr. G")+(TRIM(E2:E5)="Mr. G")>0))`? Yes, it's a long formula, it's hard to maintain, but it will work.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(d,FILTER($B$2:$C$5,($D$2:$D$5=B$7)+($E$2:$E$5=B$7))=$A8,SUM(N((INDEX(d,0,1)+INDEX(d,0,2))>0)))
```

[image]

- FILTER columns B and C for those rows where either teacher column is equal to the value in the header of the summary table (e.g. Mr. G)
- Compare that filtered result to the row header of the summary table (e.g. Star). This will create a 2-dimensional array populated with TRUE or FALSE
- Call the array of TRUE/FALSE "d"
- Take the first column of d and add it to the second column of d, then convert the result to an array of numbers. This will then be a one-dimensional array of numbers which are either 0 or greater than 0. The rows that are greater than 0 represent a "match" where the teacher and the student class has been found.
- Check this one-dimensional array for rows which are greater than zero. This will create an array of TRUE/FALSE.
- Sum this array to get the required result

nb. if you don't have access to LET, you can use this instead:

```
=SUM(N((INDEX(FILTER($B$2:$C$5,($D$2:$D$5=B$7)+($E$2:$E$5=B$7))=$A14,0,1)+INDEX(FILTER($B$2:$C$5,($D$2:$D$5=B$7)+($E$2:$E$5=B$7))=$A14,0,2))>0))
```